# Gnome extensions notification since 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, notification, gnome-shell-extension

I recently upgraded to 18.04 and since then, I've been receiving a "gnome extensions" notification.

When I click on it, I get this screen on my browser.

[image]

My questions are:

- What are these extensions for?
- Are they extensions for the browser?
- How can I disable this particular notification ... if I decide not to install these extensions?

Answer (score 2):

> What are these extensions for?

To extend funtionality of your desktop

> Are they extensions for the browser?

No.

> I've been receiving a "gnome extensions" notification.

You get these because you have 3 of them active. Probably means it is telling you you need to update them since you probably are using the 16.04 versions.

> How can I disable this particular notification ... if I decide not to install these extensions?

You can disable the notifications in "settings" on all or on individual options.

[image]

Comment: Nice detailed answer, but there is no way to disable only this kind of notification from Settings > Notifications, you'll have to disable notification from your browser altogether. A better alternative would be to disable "check for GNOME shell extensions update" option from the preferences of the "GNOME Shell Integration" browser add-on/extension: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqtVW.png.

Comment: That makes life easier. Done :)

Comment: Thanks, but "extension update notifier" doesn't provide an option to disable "check for GNOME shell extensions update" completely if I'm not mistaken, only lets you set the interval length of checking. That option is provided by the *browser add-on/extension* called "GNOME Shell integration" which extensions.gnome.org asks to install once you visit the site (for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/).